# Telegram Bot api custom keyboard additional data values

Tags: api, telegram-bot

Is there any way to pass additional data values from custom keyboard layout buttons?

I need to pass a value like ID that they are hidden from user:

```
{"Button1",{"id":1}} ...
```

Comment: If u wana a simple answer : your answer would be no !

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it with custom keyboards, but it is possible with *callback_data* param of [InlineKeyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup)

When user will press inline button with *callback_data* specified message received by bot will be type of [CallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery) with *data* param containing your data from the button.

Comment: Sure, but that is still not enough because `callback_query["message"]["text"]` doesn't hold the `inlinekeyboardbutton` label, but the text that its associated message originally had.
What the developer wants is like HTML input; it has "name" and "value". Currently there is no such thing available on Telegram bot API.

Answer (score 0):

That's not currently possible. It would be a great addition to the API, though, in order to separate the text you see from the value you send back to the bot.